# jquery: hide error message after validation

Tags: jquery

I'm new with jquery. I want to display an error message when the entry is not a number. The problem here when the user deletes the inputs and correctly writes a number, the error message will still appears .
How I can solve this problem ?

```
$("#SpecCode").mousedown( function() {
    specialismCode=$(this).val();
    if (!$.isNumeric(specialismCode) || specialismCode.length !=''){
        $("#SpecCode").parent().after('<span class="validation">Please enter correct input</span>');
        }

        });
```

Comment: Why would a length ever be equal to `''` (a string)?

Comment: if not, the error message will appears before the user touch the keyboard

Comment: `.length` returns a number. If there is no length, it returns `0`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER UPDATE**

If you need to show/hide the validation message you can add it directly to the html fragment and use the [.toggle(true/false)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display).

```js
$("#SpecCode").on('input',  function(e) {
    var specialismCode = $(this).val();
    var nextele = $(this).next('span');
    nextele.toggle(!$.isNumeric(specialismCode) || specialismCode.length == 0);
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <label for="SpecCode">Number:
        <input type="text" id="SpecCode"><span class="validation">Please enter correct input</span>
    </label>
</form>
```

You have some issues in your code.

Instead of:

```
specialismCode.length !=''
```

you can use:

```
specialismCode.length == 0
```

Instead of **mousedown** you can use **input**.

Finally, the error message comes after the input field. So, you can use:

```
$(this).next('span')
```

in order to select the error message.

The snippet:

```js
$("#SpecCode").on('input',  function(e) {
    var specialismCode = $(this).val();
    var nextele = $(this).next('span');
    if (!$.isNumeric(specialismCode) || specialismCode.length == 0) {
        $(this).after(function(idx, txt) {
            return (nextele.length == 0) ? '<span class="validation">Please enter correct input</span>' : '';
        });
    } else {
        nextele.remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label for="SpecCode">Number:
        <input type="text" id="SpecCode">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Obviously, I need to spend more time on jquery to learn it perfectly.